# ASP.NET MVC Areas routing not working with default route

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes, asp.net-mvc-areas

I am trying to separate my MVC project into multiple areas. So i have 3 areas 1) crm 2)services 3) Web. I want PublicWeb to be my default one. that means it should be accessed like www.mysitename.com/mycontroller/myaction( no area name inbetween) and other two to be accessed with the area name (www.mysitename.com/crm/mycontroller/myaction). What routing/ Area configuration i should have ? I tried  `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();` and it works only for my default one (web). When i access the other 2, it threw 404 error.

I tried to register indidually like the below one

```
        var area2reg = new crmAreaRegistration();
        var area2context = new AreaRegistrationContext(area2reg.AreaName, RouteTable.Routes);
        area2reg.RegisterArea(area2context);

        var area1reg = new webAreaRegistration();
        var area1context = new AreaRegistrationContext(area1reg.AreaName, RouteTable.Routes);
        area1reg.RegisterArea(area1context);
```

Then my publicweb works. But when i access my forum it threw this error,

> Multiple types were found that match the controller named 'home'. This can happen if the route that services this request ('crm/{controller}/{action}/{id}') does not specify namespaces to search for a controller that matches the request. If this is the case, register this route by calling an overload of the 'MapRoute' method that takes a 'namespaces' parameter.

My RegisterArea function for `web` is this

```
    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "web_default",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }

        );
    }
```

and the one for **`crm`** is this

```
    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "crm_default",
            "crm/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

How do i handle this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Jonathan S's solution is definitely worth a try, but you might consider a different approach. That would be to put your `web` files in the default locations. The routing engine would not look in the Area's for those files when no Area is part of the request.

Answer (score 2):

From what I can see the area routes look fine.  Did you update the default route in your Global.asax to send requests to the web area?

Something like:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { area = "web", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

    }
```

Comment: yes, im tried a lot to use default routing and area together .so this should be the correct solution .